# Generating PWM at pin PD5 of ATmega328P

Tags: pwm, atmega, atmel, atmega328pb

I am beginner to ATmega328P programming for PWM generation.
I am trying to generate a PWM wave at PD5 pin the datasheet says PD5(OC0B/T1/PCINT21).
When I generate the PWM with help of timer0 overflow interrupt it works fine, however when I try to use timer1(tccr1a, tccr1b, icr1, ocr1b) and compb_vect isr it doesn't work. Can someone please guide how I can generate PWM at PD5 pin with the help of timer1? Can you please guide is it possible to use timer1 to generate PWM at PD5?

Comment: But OC**0**B is a Timer**0**/Counter**0** output compare match B output. Thus if you want to use a Timer**1** you need to use OC**1**A (PB1) or OC**1**B (PB2)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, so can I conclude that for PWM generation at PD5 only timer0 can be used and timer1 for PB1 and PB2 pin only?

Comment: That's right at least if we are talking about a hardware PWM.